# Trying to get each line, but only returns first character in the loop

Tags: c

So i have a while loop to read comments off a text file as follows. There could be things after the comments so that shouldn't be ruled out. Here is my code as follows:

```
int i = 0;
while(!feof(fd) || i < 100) {
    fscanf(fd, "#%s\n", myFile->comments[i]);
    printf("#%s\n", myFile->comments[i]);
    getch();
    i++;
}
```

Comment format:

```
# This is a comment
# This is another comment
```

Any idea why it **only returns the first character**?

**EDIT:**

Here is my comments array:

```
char comments [256][100];
```

Comment: Please stop using `while !feof()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Also, in `while()` you probably want `&&`, not `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments array allows for 256 strings of up to 100 characters each.
The scanset `" %99[^\n]"` will skip leading whitespace and scan up to 99 (to allow for a terminating '\0') characters or to a newline whichever comes first.
The if condition will print the line and increment `i` on a commented line.

```
int i = 0;
char comments[256][100];
while( i < 256 && ( fscanf(fd, " %99[^\n]", comments[i]) == 1)) {
    if ( comments[i][0] == '#') {
        printf("%s\n", comments[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `scanf` with `%s` reads until `' '` or `'\n'` or `EOF`. Use something like `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

`"%s"` does not save spaces.

It reads and discards leading white-space and then saves non-white-space into `myFile->comments[i]`

```
// reads "# This ", saving "This" into myFile->comments[i]
fscanf(fd, "#%s\n", myFile->comments[i]);
// Prints "This"
printf("#%s\n", myFile->comments[i]);
// reads and tosses "i"
getch();

// next fails to read "s a comment" as it does not begin with `#`
// nothing saved in myFile->comments[i]
fscanf(fd, "#%s\n", myFile->comments[i]);
// output undefined.
printf("#%s\n", myFile->comments[i]);
```

---

Instead, avoid `scanf()`.  To read a line of input use `fgets()`

```
char buf[100];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  if (buf[0] == '#') printf("Comment %s", &buf[1]);
  else printf("Not comment %s", buf);
}
```